# jquery .ajax GET shows error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have spend two hours to create a very small jquery ajax snippet, but this doesn't work and it makes me crazy.
Something is wrong and I cannot find it? I do not actually know how to debug this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#subForm').submit(function (e) {            
        $.ajax({
            url: 'subscribe.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: "id = " + 2,  //EDIT: I have changed this to "id=2", but also not working                  
            success: function(result){
                alert("token recieved: " + result);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured!')
            },                  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

subscribe.php works if it is called directly:

```
<?php  
   include "conf.php";      
   $email = 'test';
   $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES("'.$email.'")';
   mysql_query($query);

  echo 'Success';
  exit;    
?>
```

This gives me text "Error occured!" and then page is redirected to "subscribe.php".
I first had getjson call, but it didn't work and I decided to changed it to .ajax get.

1) Why error occures?

2) And afterwards - even if it is error, why user is redirected to subscribe.php, this is ajax and why user is not stayed on the same page?

**EDIT**
If I add return false, then user is not redirected to subscribe.php. This is solved.

This is solved, by changing data: "id=2".

Comment: Try looking in the network tab at what the server responds with

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of your $('#subForm').submit so that the form is not submitted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your javascript.

```
data: "id = " + 2
```

try instead:

```
data: "id="+"2"
```

otherwise you try to add the number 2 to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in `data: "id = " + 2`. And also use `e.preventDefault()`

### What will it do?

If you have spaces then that space will also be considered as part of parameters when request will be sent.

Like: `id%20=%202`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/subscribe.php',
    type: 'GET', 
    data: "{id: 2}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,                   
    success: function(result){
        alert("token recieved: " + result);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured!');
    },                  
});
```

and in your PHP , try to first echo the $_GET.

see you receive a get with key value as sent from the javascript.

Comment: I have removed all spaces and now it is "data: "id=2", also I have included var_dump ($_GET) and this gives me nothing. So something else is wrong.

Comment: i edited the answer , try now , and see if you get info in the var dump.

Comment: also , have you tested that the submit function is even called ? 
first thing in the submit function write -> console.log('submit function hit');

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use something like this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subForm').submit(function () { 
      window.open('subscribe.php?id='+id);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The following is in case you want the results displayed in current page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>      
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subForm').submit(function () { 
      $('<PUT THE DIV ID/CLASS HERE>').load('subscribe.php?id='+id);
    });
  });
</script>
```

PS: I could very well be overlooking a reason why the OP does not use this, if that is the case just ignore my answer.